# Change the Azure Domain I'm working on

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have to switch to an AzureAD Domain to work on it.

Problem is,  I didn't find anything to change it.

I have 2 domains on my O365 account. When I connect with `Connect-AzureAD`, I'm logged into the first domain.

I want to switch to the other domain. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the **TenantId** to connect to Azure AD:

```
connect-azuread -TenantId
```

Comment: Got this "Tenant XXX not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator."

Comment: @Naeso Could you please check your tenantID with this `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/.well-known/openid-configuration`?

Comment: there is... lot of stuff right now on the screen. What I am suppose to find ?

Comment: Finded. I have to go though my Azure Portal,  Download the "PortalDiagnostic.Json" file, and my TenantID for the second domain was in there. Using you command, and now I'm on the right thing. Thanks.